# Very small, persistent data structure

Tags: php, database, json, apache, data-structures

I'd like to make a very, very small, but persistent data structure that I can reference quickly server-side, and I'm not sure how.

Basically, what I want is an array that holds little structures that hold 3-10 strings in them. The array would be of size somewhere from 50-5,000 (expandable).

I was considering using a database, but that seems like overkill in this case. I was considering using a file that held JSON, but that just doesn't seem right (I think my server would have to load the file, parse the file, then return every time the cgi is called).

I'd like to be able to have PHP get something out of this persistent data structure in constant, fast time every time it's called.

I'm currently using just vanilla Apache and PHP.

Comment: Use a file, and cache contents to APC to avoid unnecessary reads ? How often does the data get updated?

Comment: Have you looked at SQLite? It's a very basic database of just one file  for which you don't need to install anything extra on the server; it works out of the box in PHP.

Comment: I'd also consider using memcached - That way at least it will be in memory and spare the disk I/O

Comment: @OneTrickPony the data would get updated every day or so. I don't know what APC is right now, and I don't know what memcache is right now. I'll look up both of those. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without a file APC can store those data! apc_fetch and apc_store. The only problem is that the data is restricted to one server, so as soon as you will have clusters or multiple servers they don't share the data. (http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.apc.php)

If multiple servers are involved, memcached or redis are worth a check. Redis has built-in arrays.

Edit:

Check if json_encode/json_decode are as fast as serialize/unserialize for your scenario or even faster, jsonlib can be real fast. It removes some php-specific data, which is probably unnecessary for you (object names etc).

Edit2: If the server crashes, the plain apc-solution will lose all data. That is the reason you should also write it to a file if needed. apc is inside the apache process so it will be faster than memcached or redis.

Comment: I'm looking into APC now. Couple of questions: 1. Does the cache get stored over server reboots? 2. Can I manually alter the APC directly from the server? Thanks!

Comment: Let me be a bit clearer: Any changes to the cache will probably be done manually serverside, unless I choose to add a nicer interface for it on the client-end (which only one or two people would use, not the average user). This data structure would primarily be read out of by php. If it gets wiped on server reboots, I'm okay with that as long as I can store all the information in a text file or something (JSON, whatever, doesn't matter) and restore it manually.

Comment: "directly from the server" via php-scripts (admin-scripts). Persistence over restarts only via `apc_bin_dump` / `apc_bin_load`, then you should know when something has to be written. Redis saves a database file, so that would have more persistence, and has a simple client to connect to redis. But I would restrict redis-access to very little number of servers, so not via public internet, since your data is in it.

Comment: @River: I would advise setting a variable `is_loaded` in apc. If that is empty, read a json-file and set the variable `is_loaded` as well as the real data. Then you can edit the json at the server or upload or write via php. Another "admin"-script reloads the file into apc whith the right command.